# Line by line comparison of two xml files

Tags: python, xml, compare

I would like to compare 2 xml files which have similar format.

Example `f1.xml`:

```
<apple name="a" mb="15" lb="0" write="true" value="1"/>
<apple name="b" mb="31" lb="16" write="true" value="2"/>
<apple name="c" mb="32" lb="32" write="true" value="3"/>
```

Example `f2.xml`:

```
<apple name="a" mb="15" lb="0" write="true" value="1"/>
<apple name="b" mb="31" lb="16" write="true" value="3"/>
<apple name="c" mb="32" lb="32" write="true" value="2"/>
```

I would like to compare line by line and print out if the value is different for the same apple name.

How can i do that with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make your xml valid xml by giving it a root element.

Then use lxml to parse it.

Then compare them using whatever functions you like.

This example isn't the shortest way to do it, but it does break it down in a way that shows a lot of the different functions you could use.

```
from lxml import etree

def dem_apples(xml1,xml2,join_on='name'):

    tree1 = etree.fromstring(xml1)
    tree2 = etree.fromstring(xml2)

    for a1 in tree1.xpath('./apple'):
        a1_attr_set = set(dict(a1.attrib).items())
        a2_list = tree2.xpath('./apple[@{0}="{1}"]'.\
         format(join_on,a1.get(join_on)))
        for a2 in a2_list:
            a2_attr_set =  set(dict(a2.attrib).items())
            diff = a1_attr_set - a2_attr_set
            if diff:

                print(a1.get(join_on),diff,a2_attr_set-a1_attr_set)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    xml_string1="""
    <fruit>
    <apple name="a" mb="15" lb="0" write="true" value="1"/>
    <apple name="b" mb="31" lb="16" write="true" value="2"/>
    <apple name="c" mb="32" lb="32" write="true" value="3"/>
    </fruit>
    """

    xml_string2="""
    <fruit>
    <apple name="a" mb="15" lb="0" write="true" value="1"/>
    <apple name="b" mb="31" lb="16" write="true" value="3"/>
    <apple name="c" mb="32" lb="32" write="true" value="2"/>
    </fruit>
    """
    dem_apples(xml_string1,xml_string2)
```